# how to join two databases in php laravel query builder?

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

I am trying to join two databases in query builder php laravel but not finding any solution any where kindly help if anyone knows this.

```
$users = \DB::connection('mysql')->table('users as u')->join(\DB::connection('mysql2')->table('mcc_pharma_user as p'),'u.id','p.user_id')->select('*')->get();
```

I have tried this it is not working..

Answer (score -1):

By default, Laravel's sample environment configuration.

Please open **.env** file. Edit database and user, password.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

The database configuration for your application is located at **config/database.php**. In this file you may define all of your database connections, as well as specify which connection should be used by default. Examples for most of the supported database systems are provided in this file.

Using Multiple Database Connections

When using multiple connections, you may access each connection via the connection method on the DB facade. The name passed to the connection method should correspond to one of the connections listed in your config/database.php configuration file:

```
$users = DB::connection('mysql')->select(...);
```

You may also access the raw, underlying **PDO** instance using the getPdo method on a connection instance:

```
$pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
```

Running Raw SQL Queries

```
$users = DB::connection('mysql')->select('select * from users where active = ?', [1]);
```